# Different outputs of for-each loops in Java

Tags: java, loops, foreach

There is a large pile of socks that must be paired by color. Given an array of integers representing the color of each sock, determine how many pairs of socks with matching colors there are.
So I have used this method, But I am getting different outputs, I want to know the reason for the different output when I use for-each loops in Java while getting the values from the user.

Example 1:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int[] hash = new int[300];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            hash[in.nextInt()]++;
        }
        long ans=0;
        for(int p: hash){
            ans+=p/2;
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting the output `2`.

Example 2:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hash[]={1,2,1,2,3,1,2};
        long ans=0;
        for(int p: hash){
            ans+=p/2;
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting the output `4`.

Why is this so?

Comment: print your hash array before for each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you have a problem with your code `hash[in.nextInt()]++;`

You are reading the values and adding it to your hash array meaning (i.e. 1 2 1 2 3 1 2) when you enter 1 you are storing it on the index 1 and when you storing 2 you are storing it on the 2nd index and when you store your third input i.e. 1 you are overriding it the index 1 value.

what you need to do is replace `hash[in.nextInt()]++;` with  `hash[i] = in.nextInt();`